# Results from cursor into temp table with number of rows and execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor, temp-tables

There is need to fetch 100 IDs from Employee table, using cursor, then to execute stored procedure and to put number of rows and execution time for each ID into one temp table. Some idea, how to count number of rows which stored procedure will catch and execution time for that ?

```
declare @temptable table
( ID nvarchar
 , numberOfRows int
 , executionTime int)

declare @id nvarchar(15)

declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR
select top 100 NationalIdNumber
from HumanResources.Employee

open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @id

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

insert into @temptable

exec [dbo].[uspEmployeeData] @id

fetch next from db_cursor into @id

end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

I am using SQL Server 2014 Standard edition

Comment: Add an `OUTPUT` parameter to the called proc to return the desired row count, where it can be used in the outer script as needed,

Comment: Who don’t you insert the 100 all at once? Why the cursor?

Comment: The amount of time will be significantly less if you stop using a cursor for inserts. But seriously, no idea what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
declare @tableresults TABLE (@id INT, row_count INT, durationms int)

DECLARE @starttime DATETIME

open db_cursor
fetch next from db_cursor into @id

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

    SET @starttime = GETDATE()

    insert into @temptable
    exec [dbo].[uspEmployeeData] @id

    INSERT INTO @tableresults
    VALUES (@id, @@rowcount, DATEDIFF(millisecond, @starttime, GETDATE() )

    fetch next from db_cursor into @id
end
```

Comment: you have insert into temptable, then insert into tableresults, don't get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Find my first `Cursor` query.

**Note:**

Here I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2012`

I take Ids from temp table. Whereas you use actual table.

And you ask temp table as a result. But I create actual table.

You must start from `CountAgainstId` procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
 EmpID int
 , EmpName varchar (50) NOT NULL
 , Salary int NOT NULL
 , Address varchar (200) NOT NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmpID,EmpName,Salary,Address) VALUES(1,'Mohan',12000,'Noida')
, (1,'Mohan',12000,'Noida')
, (2,'Pavan',25000,'Delhi')
, (3,'Amit',22000,'Dehradun')
, (4,'Sonu',22000,'Noida'), (4,'Sonu',22000,'Noida')
, (5,'Deepak',28000,'Gurgaon'), (5,'Deepak',28000,'Gurgaon'), (5,'Deepak',28000,'Gurgaon')
GO 

-- I inserted same rows.

SELECT * FROM #Employee
```

**#Employee:**

```
EmpID   EmpName     Salary      Address
1       Mohan       12000       Noida
1       Mohan       12000       Noida
2       Pavan       25000       Delhi
3       Amit        22000       Dehradun
4       Sonu        22000       Noida
4       Sonu        22000       Noida
5       Deepak      28000       Gurgaon
5       Deepak      28000       Gurgaon
5       Deepak      28000       Gurgaon
```

**Cursor Query:**

```
create procedure RowCounts (
 @EmpId int
 , @Nos int output 
 , @RunTime int output
)
as 
begin 
 declare @StartTime datetime
 , @EndTime datetime

 set @StartTime = (select getdate ())
 set @nos = (select COUNT (*) from #employee where EmpID = @EmpId)
 set @EndTime = (select GETDATE ())

 /*
   Do further, what do you want.
 */
 set @RunTime = DATEDIFF (MILLISECOND, @StartTime, @EndTime)
end

*****************************************

create procedure CountAgainstId as
begin

 declare @RowCount int
 , @RunTime int
 , @EmpId int
 , @i int = 0

 declare CountCursors cursor
 static for
  select empid from #employee
 open CountCursors

 fetch next from CountCursors into @empid

 if OBJECT_ID ('dbo.Summaries') is null -- object_id() is not recognised the temp tables
  begin 
   create table Summaries (Empid int, NoOfRow int, ExecutionTime int)
  end
  else 
  begin
   truncate table Summaries  
  end

 while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 begin 

  if not exists (
   select * from Summaries where empid = @EmpId  -- for removing the duplicate empid's
  )
  begin

   exec RowCounts @EmpId, @RowCount output, @RunTime output

   insert into Summaries 
   values (@EmpId, @RowCount, @RunTime)

  end

  fetch next from CountCursors into @empid
 end

 CLOSE CountCursors
 DEALLOCATE CountCursors

 select * from Summaries
end
```

**Summaries** (Output Table):

```
Empid   NoOfRow     ExecutionTime
1       2           0
2       1           0
3       1           0
4       2           0
5       3           0
```

Let me know, what did you got.